# Multiple conditions in GraphQL "where"-argument will ignore the second condition

Tags: wordpress, graphql, advanced-custom-fields

I'm experimenting with an old football club Wordpress site, trying to rebuild it in a Vue.js app using wpgraphql to get the data I want.

In order to get a list of custom fields for custom post types, I came up with this general query:

```
query myQuery {
  playerProfile {
    edges {
      node {
        playerProfile {
          firstname
          team
          lastname
          number
          position
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, to filter my results by custom field values, I added these filters to my functions.php:

```
add_action('graphql_register_types', function () {

    $customposttype_graphql_single_name = "PlayerProfile";

    register_graphql_field('RootQueryTo' . $customposttype_graphql_single_name . 'ConnectionWhereArgs', 'playerProfileTeam', [
        'type' => 'String',
    ]);
});

add_filter('graphql_post_object_connection_query_args', function ($query_args, $source, $args, $context, $info) {

    $player_team = $args['where'][playerProfileTeam'];

    if (isset($player_team)) {
        $query_args['meta_query'] = [
            [
                'key' => 'team',
                'value' => $player_team,
                'compare' => '='
            ]
        ];
    }

    return $query_args;
}, 10, 5);

add_action('graphql_register_types', function () {

    $customposttype_graphql_single_name = "PlayerProfile";

    register_graphql_field('RootQueryTo' . $customposttype_graphql_single_name . 'ConnectionWhereArgs', 'playerProfilePosition', [
        'type' => 'String',
    ]);
});

add_filter('graphql_post_object_connection_query_args', function ($query_args, $source, $args, $context, $info) {

    player_position = $args['where']['playerProfilePosition'];

    if (isset($player_position)) {
        $query_args['meta_query'] = [
            [
                'key' => 'position',
                'value' => $player_position,
                'compare' => '='
            ]
        ];
    }

    return $query_args;
}, 10, 5);
```

**Here is what I want to achieve:**

```
query myQuery {
  playerProfile (where: {playerProfileTeam:"First Team", playerProfilePosition: "Goalkeeper"}) {
    edges {
      node {
        playerProfile {
          firstname
          team
          lastname
          number
          position
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will output ALL players with "playerProfilePosition": "Goalkeeper" but ignore the value for "playerProfileTeam" entirely.
If I filter for playerProfilePosition or playerProfileTeam separately, I will get the correct results. Filtering for both however will always ignore playerProfileTeam.

I assumed that adding multiple conditions separated by a comma will check for both conditions, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution.

Appearantly, the way I did it, both filters in functions.php were treated individually and wouldn't work together.

All I had to do is merge both filters together. This way I can also switch the relation to "OR" and it does just what it's supposed to.

So here is what I did to make it work:

```
add_filter('graphql_post_object_connection_query_args', function ($query_args, $source, $args, $context, $info) {

    $spieler_team = $args['where']['playerProfilTeam'];
    $spieler_position = $args['where']['playerProfilPosition'];

    if (isset($player_team, $player_position )) {
        $query_args['meta_query'] = [
            'relation' => 'AND',
            [
                'key' => 'team',
                'value' => $player_team,
                'compare' => '='
            ],
            [
                'key' => 'position',
                'value' => $player_position,
                'compare' => '='
            ]
        ];
    }

    return $query_args;
}, 10, 5);
```